# What is the proper insulation assembly for porch

Tags: insulation

Newly built porch is poor construction quality and leaky (air, not water).  Siding is T1-11 with many double insulated vinyl windows.  Porch size is about 14'x20'.

We have caulked and will spray foam insulate.

Goal is to have a 3 season room and use an electric heater in it.  We are in a northern climate.

Can I put 2" XPS Blue or Pink and cover with paneling or do I need a vapor retarder?

Do I need the XPS with the silver vapor retarder layer and which direction do I put the silver layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from local contractor "Use 1 inch or greater XPS.  By itself in the walls it is a vapor barrier.  Space it away from exterior wall so there is an air gap.  For ceiling, used foil faced XPS, foil side down.towards interior space."